# Markdown links to MS-Word hyperlinks using C# interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, markdown, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to take markdown links in a excel file and converting them to a word hyperlink in a word file. I didn't find a conversion tool but if anyone has something in mind, please let me know.

I cannot convert the whole file, have blocks of markdown that has to me transferred back in forth from QnAMaker (TSV file) to a word document to easily change content and track modifications.

Right now, the code works to go back and forth from a tsv file to a docx file.

### Table used:

```
Question  Answer  Source  Metadata          
q1        A1      S1      M1
Q2        A2      S2      M2
```

### Example

#### Markdown:

```
For more tips,  go to the [Resources and Training](http://icweb.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/029.nsf/eng/h_00205.html) page.
```

#### Word:

For more tips,  go to the [Resources and Training](http://icweb.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/029.nsf/eng/h_00205.html) page.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).